# Сколько на свете "провидений" ?

Tags: морфология

Меняется ли смысл этого слова, когда мы меняем ударение? Я нашел два ответа: Яндекс - научн. провИдение (предвидение); и wikipedia - Божье провидЕние (промысел, промышление). Верить сразу двум?

Answer (score 4):

Верьте сразу.

ПРОВ***И***ДЕНИЕ, -я; ср. Книжн.
Мысленное представление себе будущего; предвидение. Гениальное п.

ПРОВИД***Е***НИЕ; ПРОВИД***Е***НЬЕ, -я; ср. Книжн.
Высшая божественная сила, направляющая судьбы людей и всего мира к благу; промысл Божий. Как провидению угодно. Храни вас п. Оказаться где-л. волею провидения.
(БТС)

Такие значения, отличающиеся ударением, подтверждаются многими словарями. Да они в общем-то и "на слуху".